# Node.js + node-tds + Sql Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to follow the node-tds example on how to connect and retrieve data from Sql server with node.js http://cretz.github.com/node-tds/

I got no error on connect, but when I try to retrieve data I get the following:

```
"Error: Client must be in LOGGED IN state before executing sql
at TdsClient.sqlBatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\tds\lib\tds-client.js:101:13)
at Statement.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\tds\lib\tds.js:256:37)
at Statement.execute (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\tds\lib\tds.js:2:59)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\edas\app.js:67:6)
at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)
at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:38)"
```

I'm logged in, so… I can't figure out what is happening.

Comment: Could you possibly strip down your app to the minimum code required to generate that error and post it please? It is difficult to identify the issue not knowing the context in which the statement is executed.

Comment: You may also be interested in the official Microsoft node.js driver for SQL Server: https://github.com/windowsazure/node-sqlserver

Comment: I see the SQL Server 2012 tag on your question - any chance it has something to do with that? Have you tried it against a 2008r2 instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should execute your statement when the connection has already established, i.e.

```
var tds = require("tds");

var conn = new tds.Connection({
  host: "localhost",
  port: 1433,
  userName: "user",
  password: "secret",
  database: "MyDb"
});

conn.connect(function(error) {
  if (error != null) {
    console.error("Received error", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Now connected, can start using");
  }
});

conn.on("connect", function() {
    var statement = conn.createStatement("SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM Products");
    statement.on("row", function(row) {
      console.log("Received row: ", row.getValue(0));
    });
    statement.execute();
});
```